# field lines terminating at infinity

Tags: general-topology, vector-analysis

A dipole consists of two equal and opposite point
charges separated by a fixed distance.

With two exceptions, all the electric field lines
begin on one charge and end on the other.  In the 
two exceptional cases, the field lines terminate 
at infinity.

Question: It seems plausible that for any finite
configuration of point charges, there will always
exist field lines which terminate at infinity.
Is there a simple proof of this?

Comment: This sounds like a really interesting question, but I think the odds of your receiving a helpful answer will improve if you try to state your question without reference to concepts from physics.  I can sort of guess at what these terms mean but it would be best if you could more explicit from the start.  But I may just be exceptionally ignorant about such things.